# GDB pass first signal

Tags: gdb, signals, hook, segmentation-fault

I'm using a garbage collector that, for whatever reason, generates and catches a SIGSEGV during initialization.

Of course, by default GDB catches the signal. The first thing I did was `handle SIGSEGV pass nostop noprint` to pass the signal to the inferior and carry on.

However, this is getting annoying as segmentation faults are not uncommond during development, and I would really like GDB to catch them without me stopping the inferior, reinitializing the handler and continuing execution each time I start debugging.

This would be easy to accomplish using a signal hook, but I did not find any documentation for that.

In short: is there a way to pass only the first occurance of a signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New versions of gdb have "catch signal" for just this reason.  Now you can:

```
handle SIGSEGV nostop noprint pass
catch signal SIGSEGV
commands
  handle SIGSEGV stop print nopass
  # .. your breakpoint number here
  disable 1
  cont
end
```

This still isn't totally perfect (it interferes if you happen to "next" over the first SEGV), but it is pretty good.